# How can I create a truststore from a base64 encoded String?

Tags: java, truststore

I have a String that is encoded in base64, I need to take this string, decode it and create a truststore file, but when I do that, the final file is not valid. Here is my code:

```
public static void buildFile() {
    String exampleofencoded = "asdfasdfasdfadfa";
    File file = new File("folder/file.jks");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos))
    {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        String decodedString =new String(decoder.decode(exampleofencoded).getBytes());
        dos.writeBytes(decodedString);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating file");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: decoder.decode() returns already a byte array. Why don't you write these bytes directly to the file?

Comment: You're making a `String` again. Why? Very likely to fail. See @vanje's comment

Comment: Your use of a `DataOutputStream` is also wrong, a `DataOutputStream` is for writing a specific form of primitive data type serialization which doesn't apply when you want to write raw bytes to a file.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is two-fold.

1. You're converting a byte[] array to String, which is a lossy operation for actual binary data for most character sets (except maybe iso-8859-1).
2. You're using `DataOutputStream`, which is not a generic output stream, but intended for a specific serialization format of primitive types. And specifically its `writeBytes` method comes with an important caveat (*"Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits."*), which is one more reason why only using iso-8859-1 will likely work.

Instead, write the byte array directly to the file

```java
public static void buildFile() {
    String exampleofencoded = "asdfasdfasdfadfa";
    File file = new File("folder/file.jks");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath()) {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] decodedbytes = decoder.decode(exampleofencoded);
        fos.write(decodedbytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating file");
    }
}
```

As an aside, you shouldn't catch `NullPointerException` in your code, it is almost always a problem that can be prevented by careful programming and/or validation of inputs. I would usually also advise against catch the `IOException` here and only printing it. It is probably better to propagate that exception as well, and let the caller handle it.